# max width of css backgroudn image and background color

Tags: css

I have a css class that has a back ground image. I want to fix the background's image's max width to 1024px and use background color to render as the browser extends beyond that. Is there a way I can do that?

Right now, I have

```
background-size: cover;
```

And, it distorts the image height beyond 1024px.

```
.imageform {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/FPmyviO.jpg") no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #000;
```

}

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fwkqos0c/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
background-size:1024px;
```

and ypu missed

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```